# How to communicate between 2 "Azure API App" services

Tags: azure

I have 2 questions, I have 2 API Apps(api1 and api2) located in East US and I need that api1 to communicate with api2.

1. If communication is possible, how it can be done?
2. the same question but use 2 Web apps instead.

Thanks!!!

Comment: There are multiple ways - direct REST calls, Service Bus, Event hub etc. You need to pick one based on your requirements.

Comment: HTTP/HTTPS communication